# Are the given segments form a Triangle/Hexagon/Square/Parallelogram/Trapezoid/Rhombus.

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

So I am creating a game where the user can draw segments to a grid.

When he is finished, my program should decide whether he drew any of the shape mentioned above.

I have line segments with their starting and ending coordinates. Is it possible to decide this with the data I have?

[image]

Comment: Are you allowing the user to draw more than 6 segments? Also do you have an easy way in your code to count the number of segments in the drawn shape?

Comment: Yes he can draw as many segments as he wants to. And yes, I know every shape and their segments too.

Comment: Can he draw disconnected segments? If it's possible to share your code here, which language are you using?

Comment: He can connect any 2 points on the grid, I can limit this if it helps the case. I would share my code, but it's quite scattered in the files and really only does this. I really just don't know the math behind this, I'm confident in programming :D.

Comment: That's cool. But what I'm asking is whether he can draw two segments that are not sharing a point?

Comment: Sure, he can connect ANY two point without limitation. It can be 1 grid long, but can be 5 too.

Comment: so is [this](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing/xpvsdxbq) a valid shape?

Comment: This is 2 valid shape (since they are not connected), in the programs interpretation.

Comment: That means your program treats connected segments as a shape, is that right?

Comment: Then it is easy. Familiar with dot product?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100648/discussion-between-ferenc-dajka-and-pooja).

Comment: Hey do post the link to your finished game here so that I get a notification:) I'd like to see the final version

Comment: @pooja Hi, I should not comment this here, but check our chat please!